# Bash - fill empty cell with following value in the column

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a long tab-delimited CSV file and I am trying to paste in a cell a value that comes later on the column.
For instance, input.txt:

```
0 
1 
1.345 B
2
2.86 A
3
4
```

I would like an output such as:

```
0 B
1 B
1.345 B
2 A
2.86 A
3 B
4 B
```

I've been tinkering with code from other threads like [this awk solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419438/how-to-fill-empty-cells-in-a-csv-with-data-from-a-previous-cell-in-the-same-colu), but the problem is that the value I want is not before the empty cell, but after, kind of a .FillUp in Excel.

Additional information:

- input file may have different number of lines
- "A" and "B" in input file may be at different rows and not evenly separated
- second column may have only two values
- last cell in second column may not have value
- [EDIT] for the last two rows in input.txt, B is known to be in the second column, as all rows after 2.86 are not A.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you tried? Could you post some code?

Comment: "paste in a cell a value that comes late" So why/how do you infer the value `B` for the last two lines, as there is _no_ value that comes late?

Comment: Well, I have several scripts that will copy a previous filed into an empty one, such as the one I've linked or this one `awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=" " }{ if ($2 == "")
     for (i=1; i <= NF; i++)
       if ($i == "")
         $i=a[i]
   print
   split ($0,a)
}
' i2 >i3`

But I've been unable to fill cells bottom up

Comment: How do you decide to populate A or B in 2nd column?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux there can only be two values, A and B. 2.86 is the last time point that has A value, then >2.86 time points are B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ tac input.txt | awk -v V=B '{if ($2) V=$2; else $2=V; print}' | tac
0 B
1 B
1.345 B
2 A
2.86 A
3 B
4 B
```

`tac` (`cat` backwards) prints a file in reverse. Reverse the file, fill in the missing values, and then reverse it again.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but B should not be in the fourth line, A should.

Comment: @beornk What's wrong with this answer? It _seems_ to produce the exact output you where expecting... Or do I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to process the file in a single pass as long as you know the first value to fill. It should be quite a bit faster than reversing the file twice.

```
awk 'BEGIN {fillvalue="B"} $2 {fillvalue=$2=="A"?"B":"A"} !$2 {$2=fillvalue} 1' input.txt
```

Note that this assumes knowledge about the nature of that second column being only 'A' or 'B' or blank.